# Modified search ProductCollection, but pagination was wrong on the search view pape

Tags: magento, search, collections, pagination

Modified _getProductCollection function in class Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result

what i did were 
$newSearchCollection->addItem($parentProduct); // add some items back to the collection.
$newSearchCollection->removeItemByKey($singleProductId); // remove some items from the collection.

The result was correct.

But on the research view page, the pagination did not work, which still shown the old collection's pagination. and all products listed on one page no matter how many.

Anyone can help?

spent a day on this, stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks my colleague Michael :-)

Basically modifying collection will not update the collection pagination from it`s original.

What you need to do are

1. get all product ids as required
2. create a new collection using addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $allProductIds) from 'catalog/product_collection'.
   `$newSearchCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $allProductIds)
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');`
3. return $this->_productCollection = $newSearchCollection;

done. 
hope it will help someone.